# 'Search engine' on local database

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I have a webapp with multiple objects with multiple `String`s I'd like to search through. I would like to sort 'matches' by the best 'match'. Example: searching for 'stackoverflow is great'.

- "Stackoverflow is a great website".
- "This website has a great community".
- "Stackoverflow".
- "This website is good". // Here you could even consider 'is' as not being a match

Since I feel this would be reinventing the wheel, I'm searching for a library that's configurable though not monsterous. Since I don't know how this would be positioned in the application (using `JPA` or just a normal class), I think it's worth mentioning I'm using `JSF` and `JPA`.

Do you know of any library for this, configurable to which fields to search et cetera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally never used an API for this before, but I recommend [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). 
My friends used it and they didn't have any problems with it.

It has best result functions and everything, multi-platform and is open source.
I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Will try this, will accept if it seems usable. Just curious, how would you handle such a case?

Comment: I would at least try and use a testDB (maybe even JPA/JSF included) to set up a small test-enviroment. Like I said before, I haven't used it myself. Only seen it in action. But I would think there are examples in there as well for you to help you out.

Comment: I have a test environment, no problem. Though my question is about the logic. Would you split a string of searching words and search everything for `LIKE IN ARRAY()` with `SQL`? Because that would make my last example just as valid as the first one.

Comment: I think that is based on what u want. If indeed you want to even search the text with `is` if you string is `stackoverflow is great`. Otherwise I would recommend to just make the search on the line you enter. Also the API might might have setups ready for you to perform either way you want.

Comment: Ok thanks Skillcoil. +1 for your help, will accept as soon as I'm home and have been able `Lucene`.

Comment: Lucene seems to fit my needs. Thanks for your time!